# Count series where next values of cells are greater

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to count series where minimum 3 next values of cells are greater.
For example we have this numbers:

```
1
5
6
7
4
2
5
8
9
10
```

The result of the formula should be 2 ([1,5,6,7] and [2,5,8,9,10]).
I'd also like to find the length of the longest series

Comment: I believe that the easiest way is to do a function in VBA to perform this count. Have you tried anything with VBA?

Comment: @LuizLai Please don't edit questions based on assumptions. The question nowhere mentions vba and until and unless the OP mentions vba, that tag is irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could try the following:

In `B1`:

```
=MAX(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,ROW(A1:A10)),IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,"",ROW(A1:A10)))>=2,FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,ROW(A1:A10)),IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,"",ROW(A1:A10)))+1,""))
```

In `B2`:

```
=SUM(IF((IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,ROW(A1:A10)),IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,"",ROW(A1:A10)))>=2,FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,ROW(A1:A10)),IF(A1:A10<A2:A11,"",ROW(A1:A10)))+1,""))<>"",1,0))
```

**Note:** Enter both through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I do not think this satisfies the `I'd like to count series where minimum 3 next values of cells are greater`  If you change the `6` to `2` there should only be `1` that satisfies that statement and your formula returns `3`

Comment: My tunnel vision totally missed that requirement @ScottCraner. Amended.

Comment: cool, I could get the count with SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A10<A2:A11)+(A1:A10<A3:A12)+(A1:A10<A4:A13)=3)*((A2:A11<A5:A14)+(A2:A11<A3:A12)+(A2:A11<A4:A13)<>3))` but not the max